# How to minimize nested if statements? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I find that I'm often doing things of this sort in my Ruby code:

```
if person
  if person.shirt
    if person.shirt.sleeve
    ...
  end
end
```

..which I do to avoid `NoMethodErrors`. I'm wondering if there's any way that I can collapse this into one line, without the obvious

```
if person && person.shirt && person.shirt.sleeve
```

Basically, I want to make my code more compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside those ifs you want to do something with a sleeve, right?

Rails has a nice helper, [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try). It returns value if everything goes well, and `nil` otherwise. So, in this example, if `person.shirt` or even `person` itself is nil, try will return nil as well.

```
if sleeve = person.try(:shirt).try(:sleeve)
  # do your stuff
end
```

For vanilla ruby you can use [`andand`](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem which provides similar functionality.

```
if sleeve = person.andand.shirt.andand.sleeve
  # do your stuff
end
```

Since ruby 2.3, you can use safe navigation operator:

```
if sleeve = person&.shirt&.sleeve
  # do your stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Knew about try, didn't know about `andand`.